# Fractional approximation of $e$

Tags: exponential-function, fractions, pi, eulers-number-e

For $\pi$ there are the fractional approximations $\frac{22}{7}$ and the only slightly longer but much more accurate $\frac{355}{113}$.

I am aware of an analogous fractional approximation for $e$, $\frac{19}{7}$. However, this is only accurate to $1$ decimal place ($3$ digits), so not terribly practical. I would be interested to find some more accurate and hopefully not too much longer fractional representations of $e$. Is there a fractional representation for $e$ as compact as $\pi$'s $\frac{355}{113}$ with a similar accuracy?

Comment: Take truncations of the continued fraction $[2; 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 12, 1, 1, 14, 1, 1, 16, 1, 1, 18, 1, 1, ...]$

Comment: See [continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction).

Comment: This is implemented in Wolfram Alpha as [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Convergents%5Be%2C+20%5D)

Comment: That $\pi$ has such an excellent approximation with small denominator and numerator has its reason in the early large entry in the simple continued fraction. This is not the case for $e$ and much less for the golden ratio which is the worst case of an irrational number if it should be approximated by a rational number.

Answer (score 5):

The continued fraction for $\pi$ is$$3+\cfrac1{7+\cfrac1{15+\cfrac1{1+\cfrac1{\color{red}{292}+\cdots}}}}$$That $292$ is a huge number in this context, and it's because of it that we have the excellent approximation$$\pi\approx\frac{355}{113}=3+\cfrac1{7+\cfrac1{15+\cfrac11}}.$$Nothing similar occurs in the case of $e$, whose continued fraction is$$e=2+\cfrac1{1+\cfrac1{2+\cfrac1{1+\cfrac1{1+\cfrac1{4+\cfrac1{1+\cfrac1{1+\cfrac1{6+\cfrac1{1+\cdots}}}}}}}}}$$

Comment: I assume the pattern 1 1 2 1 1 4 1 1 6 etc is not coincidence but goes on like that? And that pi has no pattern like that?

Comment: This kind seems to sidestep the question---you have *assumed* that the asker is familiar with continued fractions, then showed why $\mathrm{e}$ should be less well approximable than $\pi$.  But you can approximate $\mathrm{e}$ just as well as $\pi$, assuming that you are willing to go out enough terms in the continued fraction.  It seems like a more relevant answer would actually *explain* what these continued fractions are doing.

Comment: @gnasher729 That is correct. http://oeis.org/A003417

Comment: Take a look [here](http://oeis.org/A003417).

Comment: @XanderHenderson Indeed, but that explanation would be too long for an answer, I think. I can provide a reference to the OP, should they ask for one.

Comment: By truncating $e$'s continued fraction at different points, you obtain the approximation sequence $[2, 3, 8/3, 11/4, 19/7, 87/32, 106/39, 193/71, 1264/465, 1457/536, 2721/1001, 23225/8544, 25946/9545, 49171/18089, 517656/190435, 566827/208524, 1084483/398959, ...]$.  Then it's just a matter of where to make the tradeoff between memorability and accuracy.

Comment: I'm not familiar with continued fractions myself.  I noticed above someone said $2721/1001$ was the best you could get at that size denominator.  Is that true in general for continued fractions?

Comment: @Alan: It depends on your definition of "best".

Comment: @Dan Minimal error at that  denominator or less

Comment: @Dan Why also $2/3$ and $3/3$?

Answer (score 1):

$$e \approx \frac{2721}{1001} = 2.\overline{718281}$$

This is the smallest-denominator fraction that has an absolute error ($1.102 \times 10^{-7}$) less than $|\pi - \frac{355}{113}| \approx 2.668 \times 10^{-7}$.

Answer (score 1):

One approximation that links to other problems is to render the Maclaurin series for $\exp(x)$ at $x=-1$ and simply truncate it, taking the reciprocal of the result as the approximation for $e$. Thus for instance:

$\exp(-1)\approx(1/2)-(1/6)+(1/24)-(1/120)=44/120,$

$e\approx(120/44)=(30/11)=2.72727...$

If the approximation is left with the factorial in the numerator, the denominator us the corresponding number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of the corresponding number of objects (here, $44$ derangements for five objects).

Successive approximations by this method bracket $e$ tightly.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2021/03/27/smallest-fraction/) are some good fractional approximations of $\pi$, $e$ (Napier's number), and $\phi$* in different error bounds:

*$\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ (golden ratio)

[image: approximations]

Answer (score 0):

If you like those things, then you might like this too:

$$e \approx \frac{53035 \pi }{61294} \approx 2.7182818282888(...)$$

Which yelds also to

$$\frac{e}{\pi} \approx \frac{53035}{61294}$$

and the reciprocal.